# How can I only include one match when using INNER JOIN while doing SELECT statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, select, inner-join

```
SELECT distinct
    sr.ServiceDescription,
    os.ServiceID
FROM            
    OrderedServices as os           
INNER JOIN
    Orders as o ON o.OrderID = os.OrderID
INNER JOIN
    ServiceRelation as sr ON os.ServiceID = sr.ServiceID
WHERE 
    o.OrderID = 2802882;
```

Let's say this returns something like this:

```
Service Description  | ServiceID
--------------------------------
Basic Cable          | 2
Extended Cable       | 5
ExtendedPlus Cable   | 5
Everything Cable     | 10
```

However, I only want to return a single value for `Service Description` if two `ServiceID`s match. See that `ServiceID` of 5 has two `Service Descriptions`? I only want to grab one of them. How can I modify the select statement above to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `MAX()`,`MIN()` or `Row_Number()`

```
SELECT distinct
    max(sr.ServiceDescription),
    os.ServiceID
FROM            
    OrderedServices as os           
INNER JOIN
    Orders as o ON o.OrderID = os.OrderID
INNER JOIN
    ServiceRelation as sr ON os.ServiceID = sr.ServiceID
WHERE 
    o.OrderID = 2802882 group by  os.ServiceID;
```

Or

```
SELECT distinct
        MIN(sr.ServiceDescription),
        os.ServiceID
    FROM            
        OrderedServices as os           
    INNER JOIN
        Orders as o ON o.OrderID = os.OrderID
    INNER JOIN
        ServiceRelation as sr ON os.ServiceID = sr.ServiceID
    WHERE 
        o.OrderID = 2802882 group by  os.ServiceID;
```

Or

```
 ;with cte as
    (
    SELECT distinct
                sr.ServiceDescription,
                os.ServiceID,
               Row_Number() Over(partition by os.ServiceID order by  os.ServiceID)           
 as rn
            FROM            
                OrderedServices as os           
            INNER JOIN
                Orders as o ON o.OrderID = os.OrderID
            INNER JOIN
                ServiceRelation as sr ON os.ServiceID = sr.ServiceID
            WHERE 
                o.OrderID = 2802882
    )
    select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: If  you do max you need group by.

Comment: Excellent, I went with min. I could do the max or min one and that's what I'm looking for. Thank you!